# IIS 10.0 Detailed Error - 405.0 - Method Not Allowed on Windows Server 2016

Tags: php, iis

I am using PHP version 7.2.7 on IIS. Everything was working fine until I started getting this error about a week ago:

> IIS 10.0 Detailed Error - 405.0 - Method Not Allowed

This is using a POST method.

I checked the Handler Mappings for ***.php** and POST is listed. And WebDAV is not installed.

I have not changed anything in IIS in months. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

When POSTing to a URL without a file extension, be sure to include the trailing / . Omitting this causes the same error.

From [iis.net](https://forums.iis.net/t/1154637.aspx?HTTP%20Error%20405%200%20Method%20Not%20Allowed) :

> If you do a POST to /postreceiver/ (note the trailing /), you should
>   not see the problem - the reason why you cannot POST to /postreceiver
>   is that we cannot just transfer control to /postreceiver/default.aspx
>   on the server side as any relative links generated by that page would
>   be incorrect on the client (because the new url is at a different
>   level), so we have to first redirect the client to /postreceiver/
>   which is fine for GETs, but for POSTs, most clients when redirected
>   will drop the POST body and just do a GET so it does not work.